# how to unit test methods with dependencies

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependencies

I need to create some unit testing for my application but I am not sure how to proceed and I couldn't find anything of help online. What I want to know is how to test an app where there are many methods dependent on a few others.

e.g.

```
public class foo(){

    public void doIt() {
        boz();
        bar();
        biz.baz(); //from another class
    }

    public void bar(){
        ...
    }

    public int boz(){
        ...
    }

}
```

so in a scenario like the one presented above one would think that unit testing the `doIt` method would be sufficient since it is going to fail anyway if something is wrong with the methods called inside it.

Although, I am not sure if we can consider this to be **unit** testing as this tests the functionality of more than just an entity. In addition, if the test on the `doIt` method fails it is going to be really hard to tell where the error occurred especially in a case with many dependencies - doesn't that defy the meaning of unit testing?

So far the only approach I have thought is to start by testing the dependencies first (i.e. `bar` `boz` `baz`) and then the `doIt` method. That way, if the test suite gets to `doIt` with no errors and fails means that there is something wrong with the code implemented inside that method and not inside its dependencies.

BUT, is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: `bar` and `boz` are not dependencies since they are part of the class you are testing. In fact, `biz` is the dependency. In order to unit test `foo`, you need to make `biz` an interface instead of a concrete implementation. That way you can provide a dummy version of `biz` in your unit test.

Comment: as @KaseySpeakman mentioned `bar` and `boz` are not dependencies, they should in face be part of your test. Why don't you use a known framework such JUnit?

Comment: @KaseySpeakman isn't that a bit too much? Changing the whole implementation and creating interfaces I don't need otherwise just for the sake of unit testing? And how about the other methods? Do I test them individually as well? i.e. `boz` and `bar`

Comment: @Arsham I am planning on using JUnit indeed. but what difference does it make to the approach?

Comment: @Rakim, I won't argue that it's less work. But most will argue that your code being less coupled and more testable is a good thing in the long term. Unit tests aren't the only way, though. You should also consider [behavior testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) in addition to unit testing critical parts.

Comment: It doesn't! as we mentioned previously `bar` and `boz` are not dependency as you call them. They need to be tested separately. Usually different components (read classes) in a program are tested separately.

Answer (score 0):

To test doIt() method without having to invoke the real implementations of bar() and baz(), use a Spy in Mockito:

[Mockito spy documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)

If bar() is really void, you can do something like this:

```
foo f = spy(new foo());
doNothing().when(foo).bar();
```

Better is if you can inject your dependencies (ex: biz) as mock objects and test your foo class directly.

Comment: and test the dependencies separately? And considering that one method might have many different dependencies, that might make the size of the testing suite huge! I ll have a look at mockito though. It seems like it might be of help

Comment: Yes, you test the dependencies separately.  This is a quite common pattern, to have unit tests for each of your classes (that test each class one at a time), as well as functional/component/integration tests that test groups of classes together.